# Live Paint: make on brush produces "sharp" edges

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm following a tutorial 
[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sPuXmTLBj4&t=342s) starting around 5:15
for coloring in Illustrator. After drawing with the brush tool, I did Expand Appearance, then Live Paint → Make, which caused these "breaks" in my drawing.

[image: After Live Paint → Make]

What I want is something like this

[image]

like in the video tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, it had to do with the ellipses. I just had to flatten the ellipse / lines BEFORE doing Live Paint → Make, then Live Paint → Expand.